# elasticsearch node.ROLE configuration

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting started with ELK, and I already have a question about configuring `elasticsearch` node. Ingest node especially is not clear to me. According to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html), all three "roles" (master, data and ingest) are set to `true` by default. I understand it is for creating a singe node cluster, with all `elasticsearch` in one machine.

So if I want to have say a 3 node cluster (1 master + 2 workers), should I just set the values I don't want to false? Something like this:

**MASTER**

```
node.name: master
node.data: false
node.ingest: ?
```

**WORKERS**

```
node.name: data-x
node.master: false
node.ingest: ?
```

In this situation, where I don't have a dedicated ingest node, where should it go? It makes more sense to me to put them on data nodes, but I am not sure if this is the right assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need a dedicated ingest node. If there is considerable data transformation/enrichment  going on ( not just analyzing and indexing JSON document)  - dedicated ingest node might help. This [blog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) will give you more information.